# i need a solution for the module not working on my system

Tags: python, simplecv

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('unit test')?
as I want to just get the access of the image in the camera

Comment: You're trying to run python2.x code using python3.x

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If that's what you really wanted to print. I believe that you were using python3, in which print is a function rather than a statement(unlike python2)

For python 3:

```
print('Unit test')
```

For python 2:

```
print 'Unit test'
```